How to query fields in Directus Flows Read Data?
I have this "Read Data" in Directus Flows. I want to get result from this field: product_carts.products_cart_id. I know how to execute it from postman with /product_carts.products_cart_id. But how execute it in Directus Flows?
I tried with this:
"fields": {product_carts.products_cart_id}

or
"fields": {product_carts.*}

but nothing successfull.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I found the answer:
"fields": "*, product_carts.products_cart_id"

